# C printing a linked list not working?

Tags: c, file-io, linked-list, scanf

I am reading from a file and trying to add it into a linked list and then traversing through the linked list to print the content out. I have a little trouble since my output is not printing the entire linked list, but only the last element multiple times. I have posted code down below and I have posted only snippets, and have removed error checking for brevity.

```
typedef struct Node{
    char* data;
    struct Node* next;
} NODE;

NODE* head = NULL;
NODE* tail = NULL;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buffer[1024];
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    while(fscanf(fp, "%1023s", buffer) == 1)
    {
        addNode(buffer);
    }
    print_linked_list(head);
    return 0;
}

void print_linked_list(NODE* head)
{
    NODE* ptr = head; 
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s ", ptr -> data);
        ptr = ptr -> next;
    }
}

void addNode(char* str)
{
    NODE* newNode = createNode(str);
    if(head == tail && tail == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        head -> next = NULL;
        tail -> next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        tail -> next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        tail -> next = NULL;
    }
}

NODE* createNode(char* str)
{
    NODE* newNode = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    newNode -> data = malloc((1 + strlen(str)) * sizeof(char));
    newNode -> data = str;
    newNode -> next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
```

So if a file contains some text like "how are you", I am expecting my output to be printed as "how are you", but all I get is "you you you". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At

```
newNode -> data = malloc((1 + strlen(str)) * sizeof(char));
newNode -> data = str;
```

did you wanted to do a string copy (`strncpy()`) from `str` to `newNode->data`?

With `newNode->data = str;` the pointer is copied, the contents (e.g. "how are you") is **not** copied.

A simple way might be

```
newNode->data = strdup(str);
```

From http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdupa.3.html

> ```
>    The strdup() function returns a pointer to a new string which is a
>    duplicate of the string s.  Memory for the new string is obtained
>    with malloc(3), and can be freed with free(3).
> ```

Comment: Yeah it works for some reason, could you explain why that change works?

Comment: @lufork You are setting every node's data to the same value, a pointer to `buffer`. Thus every node has the same data.

Comment: Oh thanks guys. But one small query, I checked on another SO question and someone mentioned that strdup is non standard and hence should not be used. So would strncpy be more encouraged in general compared to strdup? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746255/linked-list-in-c-read-from-file In the comments someone wrote that strdup is not a standard function.

Answer (score 1):

`newNode->data = str;` is the problem. You're `malloc`ing space for a string, assigning that address to `newNode->data`, then immediately overwriting the address to that `malloc`ed space with the address to `str`, which actually is the address of `buffer` all the way from `main`.  Not only does this create a memory leak, but it explains your behavior.  Each time you create a node, you're assigning `newNode->data` to the address of `buffer`, so when the last word "you" is stored in `buffer`, this is the string all the nodes print.  What you really want to do is `strcpy` (or something equivalent) the string from `str` into your newly `malloc`ed space.  You should also check the return value of `malloc` first to make sure it returned a valid pointer:

```
#include <string.h>
....

if (newNode->data != NULL)
{
  strcpy(newNode->data, str);
}
else
{
   // handle error
}
```