# Read from file to linked list C

Tags: c, file-io, linked-list

I'm new to the C language, and I'm trying to make a calendar using SDL2, but for some reason my code just skips storing the first data. When I try to return with the "head" of my linked list (which stores structures), some of the data is saved, but some is not. I have a function called linecutter. It should work fine according to my tests. The structure of the file is something like
for some reason the comment part returns correctly. If I printf the location data, it returns correctly, but otherwise it doesn't work as intended.

An examle of a file used:

```
Prog spec;2020/10/05;2020/11/01;00/00;23/59;Infoc;shouldnt forget it and leave to the last min
something;2020/10/05;2020/11/01;00/00;23/59;location;just a comment
asd asd;2020/2/02;2020/9/01;00/00;23/59;Infoc;lkasjd laksdj
```

This code should print the event names twice. Once when reading the file, once when checking in the main. But it only prints when reading.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Date{
int y;
int m;
int d;
} Date;

typedef struct Time{
int h;
int m;
} Time;

typedef struct Event{
char* name;
Date startdate;
Date enddate;
Time starttime;
Time endtime;
char* location;
char* comment;
} Event;

typedef struct Lista{
Event event;
struct Lista * next;
} Lista;

Date datecreate(char*todate)
{
    Date *tmp = (Date *)malloc(sizeof(Date)*1);
    int len = strlen(todate);
    char date[len];
    strcpy(date,todate);
    char y[5];
    char m[5];
    char d[4];
    int i =0;
    for(; i<4; i++)
        y[i] = date[i];
    i++;
    for(int var = 0; i<7; var++, i++)
    {
        m[var] = date[i];
    }
    i++;
    for(int var = 0; i<10; var++, i++)
    {
        d[var] = date[i];
    }
    tmp->d = atoi(d);
    tmp->m = atoi(m);
    tmp->y = atoi(y);

    return *tmp;
}
Time timecreator(char*totime)
{
    Time tmp;

    char h[3];
    char m[3];
    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
        h[i] = totime[i];

    for(int i = 4; i<6; i++)
        m[i-4] = totime[i];

    h[3] = '\0';
    m[3] = '\0';
    tmp.h = atoi(h);
    tmp.m = atoi(m);
    return tmp;
}

Event linecutter(char* line)
{
    int i = -1;
    int loc = 0;
    char name[256], startdate[12],enddate[12],starttime[7],endtime[7],location[256],comment[512];
    do{
        i++;
        name[i] = line[loc];
        loc++;
    }
    while(name[i] !=';');
    name[i] = '\0';
    i=-1;
    do{
        i++;
        startdate[i] = line[loc];
        loc++;
    }
    while(startdate[i] !=';');
    startdate[i] = '\0';
    i=-1;
    do{
        i++;
        enddate[i] = line[loc];
        loc++;
    }
    while(enddate[i] !=';');
    enddate[i] = '\0';
    i=-1;
    do{
        i++;
        starttime[i] = line[loc];
        loc++;
    }
    while(starttime[i] !=';');
    starttime[i] = '\0';
    i=-1;
    do{
        i++;
        endtime[i] = line[loc];
        loc++;
    }
    while(endtime[i] !=';');
    endtime[i] = '\0';
    i=-1;
    do{
        i++;
        location[i] = line[loc];
        loc++;
    }
    while(location[i] !=';');
    location[i] = '\0';
    i=-1;
    do{
        i++;
        comment[i] = line[loc];
        loc++;
    }
    while(comment[i] !='\0');
    comment[i] = '\0';
    Event tmp;
    tmp.name = name;
    tmp.location = location;
    tmp.comment = comment;
    tmp.starttime = timecreator(starttime);
    tmp.startdate = datecreate(startdate);
    tmp.enddate = datecreate(enddate);
    tmp.endtime = timecreator(endtime);
    return tmp;
}


    Lista * read(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[5000];
    fp = fopen("esemenyek.txt" , "rw+");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        perror("error opening");
        return NULL;
    }
    char buf[3];
    fscanf(fp, "%3c", buf);
    if (memcmp(buf, "\xEF\xBB\xBF", 3) != 0) //this is just for the encoding stuff
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    /* ... handling the file ... */
    Lista * head= NULL;
    Lista * current = NULL;
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)!=NULL){
        Lista *node = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
        if(node == NULL)
        {
            perror("error");
            return NULL;
        }
        node->event = linecutter(line);
        node->next =NULL;
        if(head== NULL){
            current = head = node;
        } else {
            current = current->next= node;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<500; i++)
            line[i] ='\0';
    printf("%s\n", current->event.name);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return head;
}
int main(void){
    Lista * lst = read();
        Lista *move;
    for (move= lst; move!= NULL; move= move->next)
        printf("%s\n", move->event.name);
        return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong, or why is this not working? If someone could help me, I'd really appreciate it. I [found another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746255/linked-list-in-c-read-from-file), it helped me to get here, but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Why is `fp = fopen("esemenyek.txt" , "rw+");` opened `"rw+"`? Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "some are, some are not..." very vague. Post the input, what you expected and what you got...

Comment: It's opened in `rw+` just so it creates a file if it doesn't yet exist

Comment: The mode `rw+` is not a valid mode.  You could use `r+` or `w+` but you can't use `r` and `w` in a single mode string.  See C11 [§7.21.5.3 The `fopen` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3) for more details.  It is undefined what happens when you use the invalid mode; the library might do something semi-sane or might reject it completely.

Comment: Your line `current = current->next= node;` should probably not be assigning like that.  You want `current->next = node; current = node;`. The order of evaluation isn't clear in the original — there isn't a sequence point between assignments.

Comment: The loop `for(int i = 0; i<500; i++) line[i] ='\0';` is pointless (`fgets()` will null terminate the string properly), but should be replaced by `memset(line, '\0', sizeof(line));` if you keep the nullification.  `line[0] = '\0';` would be sufficient, too.